# UIview animation overriding one view to another view

Tags: ios

I'm new iphone developer i have problem uiview animation for ipad landscape mode.i have two view view1(like a split view) and view2(covered remaining window).when i touch move right to left view2 it will be overriding the view1 with moving animation.at same time when i touch move left to right view2 come and fit the old position.please share your ideas

With Regards,
Rajesh.

Answer (score 3):

Hi all i found the answer finally,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipeHandle:)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
    [recognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [secondView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];


    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizerleft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipeHandle:)];
    [recognizerleft setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
    [recognizerleft setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [secondView addGestureRecognizer:recognizerleft];
    [recognizerleft release];
    [self.view addSubview:secondView];
    [super viewDidLoad];


}
//To set the frame position of the view

- (void)rightSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"rightSwipeHandle");


    [UIView beginAnimations:@"viewanimations" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    secondView.frame=CGRectMake(360, 0, 660, 768);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

//To set the frame position of the view
- (void)leftSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"leftSwipeHandle");

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"viewanimations" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    secondView.frame=CGRectMake(200, 0, 858, 768);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correctly, you want a sliding animation between 2 views. if so:
Make a ViewController that will hold these two views. inside this view controller's .m file define a transition method that contains the following and gets called by your buttons/other action triggers:

```
CGFloat windowWidth = self.mainView.frame.size.width;
CGFloat windowHeight = self.mainView.frame.size.height;
CGRect offScreenLeft = CGRectMake(-1*windowWidth, 0.0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
CGRect onScreen = self.mainView.frame;
CGRect offScreenRight =  CGRectMake(windowWidth, 0.0, windowWidth, windowHeight);

if (direction == rightToLeft)
{ 
    rightView.frame = offScreenRight; 
    [self.view addSubview:rightView];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.65
                     animations:^{
                         leftView.frame = offScreenLeft;       
                         rightView.frame = onScreen;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [leftView removeFromSuperview];  
                     }];


}else if (direction == leftToRight){
    self.leftViewController.view.frame = offScreenLeft;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.65 
                     animations:^{
                         rightView.frame = offScreenRight;
                         leftView.frame = onScreen;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [rightView removeFromSuperview]; 
                     }]; 
    } 
}
```

In general, make sure you are adding your subview to the view currently on screen, and make sure you set the appropriate bounds. Check that your view is not nil:

```
if(myView){
    //  not nil. thats good
}else {
    //  nil. this is bad. make sure myView is being initialized properly (if at all)
}
```

Finally, make sure neither the opacity nor the alpha property on your subview is set to 0 (you'll want these at 1 if you want it to show up completely and between 0 and 1 for a transparency effect).